# Unity-How to catch logs code even when unityLogger is disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to write logs into a text file in a release build but in our release build we set

*Debug.unityLogger.logEnabled = false;*

So that app should not print logs to console (in ADB console / iOS terminal)
But even after disabling logs is there any way to catch logs in code so that I can write into a text file?

Im already aware of custom logger implementation but the current requirement is that I have to manage with the Debug.Log() itself but how to catch the logs in case of unityLogger is disabled?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your question that you want to log things when the logger is disabled?

Comment: @Jay yes, or I want to capture logs in script without printing it to console (in ADB console / iOS terminal)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution basically, we should assign our custom logger to logHandler like this

***Debug.unityLogger.logHandler = <your_custom_logger>***

So here all the logs will be finally received into your custom logger instead of printing to console.
Your custom logger class should inherit from ILogHandler.

Note: If you don't handle this implementation properly, it might go into an infinite loop and your app might crash (even in unity editor).